# What are the harmonic conjugates of the following rational function?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

List all the harmonic conjugates of the following rational function. The integration is almost impossible, Symbolab and Microsoft Math fails to arrive at the answer:
\begin{equation}
\mu(x,y) =\frac{x^2+x+y^2}{x^2+y^2}
\end{equation}

Comment: Rewrite as $1+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$. It's conjugate is $C-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$. Essentially, the complex function is $f(z)=1+\frac{1}{z}=1+\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how did you guess at that?

Comment: The $x^2+y^2$ in the denominator was the big clue to me, being $(x+yi)(x-yi)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at

$\mu(x, y) = \dfrac{x^2 + x + y^2}{x^2 + y^2} \tag 1$

in polar coordinates:

$\mu(x, y) = \dfrac{x^2 + x + y^2}{x^2 + y^2} = \dfrac{r^2 + r\cos \theta}{r^2} = 1 + \dfrac{\cos \theta}{r}; \tag 2$

with

$z = x + iy = r\cos \theta + ir\sin \theta =re^{i\theta} \tag 3$

we have

$z^{-1} = r^{-1}e^{-i\theta} = \dfrac{\cos \theta - i\sin \theta}{r} = \dfrac{\cos \theta}{r} - i\dfrac{\sin \theta}{r} \tag 4$

is holomorphic on $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$; it follows that, as long as we stay away from $r = 0$, where $\mu$ is not in any event defined, that the harmonic conjugate of $\cos \theta / r$ is $-\sin \theta / r$, up to an addidive real constant.  In $x$-$y$ coordinates, we have

$-\dfrac{\sin \theta}{r} = -\dfrac{r\sin \theta}{r^2} = -\dfrac{y}{x^2 + y^2}. \tag 5$

Thus, every harmonic conjugate of $\mu(x, y)$ is of the form

$\alpha - \dfrac{y}{x^2 + y^2}, \tag 6$

$\alpha \in \Bbb R$ a constant, in agreement with the comments of Thomas Andrews.

Comment: Thanks a lot great explanation!!!

Comment: @JasonMars:  glad to help out; since you like my answer, you might consider formal "acceptance".  Cheers!

Comment: Sure! But how can I go for the acceptance? I'm actually new here

Comment: Look for the check mark below the votes tally.  That's the "accept" button.  Click on it to accept an answer . . . Cheers!

Comment: I see you got it!  That was quick! ;)

Comment: Done thanks a bunch @RobertLewis